# Android URL sniffing on form submit OR Chrome network tab alternative in android app

Tags: android, web-services, networking, remote-server, sniffing

There are many apps that provide signup/login and some apps that share our file on internet..

Some apps want Images/file access permission but they dont need it.

How can i check if app uploading my files?

.

In chrome there is "network" tab in developers options. Is there any similar thing in android?

I want to see URL where app send my data after signup/login or on file share?

I want to find out app's ajax/curl/post request URLs.